# Powershell Convert CSV with a Column Delimited by Spaces into an array

Tags: powershell, csv

Trying to convert a column in a non-standard CSV file into an array.  I do not have an ability to change the input file since it comes from a vendor.

Here is the data in Test.csv:

```
"Format","MoTeC CSV File"
"Beacon Markers","171.091 322.385 481.229 630.624 778.92"
```

Here is my code that works:

```
$dataDir = "G:\Desktop Files\Exports"

$Test1CSV = "$dataDir\MoTeC_Test1.csv" 
$Test2CSV = "$dataDir\MoTeC_Test2.csv" 
$Test3CSV = "$dataDir\MoTeC_Test3.csv" 

Clear-Content $Test1CSV,$Test2CSV,$Test3CSV

$inputCSV = "$dataDir\Test.csv"

$BM = (Import-Csv $inputCSV | Select-Object 'MoTeC CSV File' ) | select -Property @{Name='BM' ;Expression={$_.'MoTeC CSV File'.replace(' ',',')}}| export-CSV $Test1CSV -NoTypeInformation 
set-content $Test1CSV ((get-content $Test1CSV) -replace '"' )
$BM2 = (Get-Content $Test1CSV.split(","))
$BM3 = $BM2.split(',') | out-file $Test2CSV  

$i = @{ Counter = 0 } #this sets the Lap #
Import-Csv $Test2CSV | Select-Object @{ N='Lap'; E={ (++$i.Counter) }}, @{ N='BeaconMarker'; E={ $_.'BM'.split(',')} } | Export-Csv $Test3CSV -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

The above code produces the solution I want but it seems unnecessarily complex.

Here is my output in Test3.csv which is what I want:

```
"Lap","BeaconMarker"
"1","171.091"
"2","322.385"
"3","481.229"
"4","630.624"
"5","778.92"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear why are you reading the file then storing an updated version of it then reading it back. You could simplify the conversion like this:

```bash
Import-Csv Test.csv | ForEach-Object { $i = 1 } {
    foreach ($line in $_.'MoTeC CSV File' -split '\s+') {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Lap          = ($i++)
            BeaconMarker = $line
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv MoTeC_Test3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This could also work:

```bash
(Import-Csv Test.csv).'MoTeC CSV File' -split '\s+' | 
    ForEach-Object { $i = 1 } {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Lap          = ($i++)
            BeaconMarker = $_
        }
    } | Export-Csv MoTeC_Test3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: @ljg glad it was helpful